# Is there anything judicial that can prevent Trump from taking part in the 2024 elections?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, judiciary

It seems that Donald Trump is already preparing for his 2024 campaign - especially after the Republican [CPAC in Iowa](https://www.politico.com/news/2021/06/28/2024-iowa-caucus-republican-campaign-496418).

Is there anything **judicial** that could prevent him from running in the 2024 race?

Comment: You'll want to clarify what you mean by this.  Are you asking if there are any laws on the books that would bar Mr. Trump from running?  Are you asking whether the judiciary can unilaterally decide to block a candidacy?  Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: I mean, is there anything existing (ongoing, maybe), that can be used to block him from becoming a candidate by judical methods.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, whether it's only about past events and whether there will be judicial consequences, or do we also count hypothetical future events? (what if he robs a bank next week? What if he renounces his citizenship? What if it turns out his birth certificate was forged and he's not native-born?)

Comment: @user2501323 What do you mean by "By judical (sic) methods"? "Judicial", where the federal government is concerned, means--at least for Presidential matters--the Supreme Court of the United States (e.g. the Judicial branch of the federal government). You're asking if SCOTUS can do something to block Trump from running in the 2024 US Presidential election?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of writing this, Donald J. Trump has been elected President of the United States once and has served a total of four years. He has not held the office as President or Acting President after another person was elected. Thus, according to the [22<sup>nd</sup> Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) which reads (Section 1, inapplicable parts left out):

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once.

he can be elected one more time.

There are a couple more points that need to be met to be [eligible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_the_United_States#Eligibility):

- Article II, Section 1, Clause 5 states that the President must be a natural-born citizen of the United States, 14 years a resident thereof and at least 35 years old. As Trump is still a resident of the US and has been continuously since his term in office, these requirements are met.
- The 14<sup>th</sup> Amendment bars any person who rebelled against the Constitution of the United States. This Amendment was written with the Civil War in mind, intending to exclude the Representatives and Senators of the secession states from holding a public office unless both Houses of Congress reinstate a secessionist's eligibility. This does not apply to Trump to the best of my knowledge as nobody has penned a sufficiently authoritative legal opinion that considers him to have rebelled against the Constitution.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Finally, under Article I, Section 3, Clause 7, following impeachment and conviction, the Senate may vote to bar the impeached and convicted individual from holding a federal office. This does not apply to Trump: while he was impeached twice the Senate did not vote to convict him with the necessary majority and thus also did not vote to bar him.

I am not aware of any other legal requirements a potential President may have to fulfill to be eligible. As all the requirements above are codified within the Constitution and its Amendments, I would assume that any further eligibility requirements would also have to be laid out in the Constitution itself or in a Constitutional Amendment; there are currently none. This is amplified by the quotations that [Reirab has included in their answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/67829/) which mention that the Constitutional requirements are precise and not merely a minimum. Crucially, nowhere is it mentioned that the President must be 'of good character' or similar, meaning that being convicted of a federal or state crime would *not* bar an individual from holding office. Indeed, precedent shows that it is constitutional (or at least remained unchallenged) for a person to run for President while imprisoned.<sup>[2]</sup>

Therefore, Donald J. Trump may take part in the 2024 Presidential Election.

---

**Notes:**

[1]: There is and has been ample *political* debate whether the events of the 6th January constitute a rebellion against the Constitution. However, political debates are meaningless; it would likely be up to the Supreme Court to issue a ruling on the matter and I have not yet heard of any argument carrying sufficient weight for the Supreme Court to consider it.

[2]: In the 1920 Presidential Election, third-party candidate [Eugene Debs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugene_V._Debs) stood and gained [913,664 votes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_United_States_presidential_election) (but no votes in the Electoral College) while being [sentenced to 10 years imprisonment and disenfranchisement under the Espionage Act 1917](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debs_v._United_States). Debs was not able to cast a vote for himself.

Comment: Felons are commonly disenfranchised in the US. Does that only apply to voting rights or to candidacy as well?

Comment: @o.m. it does not apply to candidacy, but good luck running a campaign from prison.

Comment: @Ryan_L: Eugene Debs did it back in 1920.  Though, he was a third-party candidate and only got 3.4% of the popular vote.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128000/discussion-on-answer-by-jan-is-there-anything-judicial-that-can-prevent-trump-fr).

Comment: This doesn't look like a *judicial* answer.

Comment: Re "to the best of my knowledge as nobody is considering him to have rebelled against the Constitution": No, of course that was considered, very prominently. The [second impeachment of President Trump](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Article_of_Impeachment_against_Donald_J._Trump_(2021)) was explicitly referring to section 3 of the 14th amendment. There were two main reasons to impeach: (1) To publicly sanction Trump's behavior and not let it pass, because in the opinion of the signers it was such a flagrant violation of the law; and (2) to prevent him from running again, under section 3.

Comment: I would suggest focusing a bit more on the point about impeachment in the answer. Given that impeachment is really the only way to actively stop someone from running for president again, and given that Trump was impeached (but not convicted or barred), the point about impeachment seems far more relevant than any of the other points. Unlike barring through impeachment, it is strictly impossible for 2 of the other points to even become true before the next election (short of some discovery that e.g. Trump wasn't born in the US or he's actually a 24-year-old).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica If Trump had been convicted upon his impeachment, he'd have presumably been barred from holding public office anyway under Article I, Section 3, so the 14th Amendment would not have been needed (technically, the Senate isn't required to place such a restriction, but, in practice, it's kind of the point of impeachment.) That was just added for dramatic effect in a document that was already intended primarily for political purposes.

Comment: @reirab I'm not telepathic so I cannot comment on the true reason the amendment 14,3 was put in there. But it was, and my statement stands, and the answer is wrong in this respect.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The answer does include a caveat addressing that specific point that the answer is referring to the lack of an authoritative legal opinion, not the lack of partisan attack rhetoric.

Comment: @RonJohn So which details would be lacking for it to become a *judicial* answer?

Comment: @o.m. See the second annotation; I wasn't sure whether it had been *tested* that conviced felons serving their sentence could stand for election but other commentors have provided an example.

Comment: @NotThatGuy I'm unsure why I should focus more on the Impeachment. The Impeachment itself does nothing, it is *conviction by the Senate* that counts. While the former President has been impeached twice, he was not convicted by the Senate once. That is all one needs to know imho.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I guess I should make it clearer that I meant any sufficiently qualified legal opinion. Politicians can say (almost) all they want all day long (including because of the First Amendment) but just because the words were uttered or scribbled doesn't mean the argument holds any legal/judicial/constitutional weight.

Comment: @Jan You can read my previous comment as "I would suggest focusing a bit more on the point about impeachment *and conviction* in the answer".

Comment: @Jan You can't get more constitutional weight than in a document of prosecution (namely the impeachment) written by the entity tasked with that prosecution by the constitution (namely the House).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica But neither the Impeachment by the House nor the Trial by the Senate were tasked with finding whether Trump had violated the 14th Amendment. The Impeachment 'indicted' Trump for high Crimes and Misdemeanors and the Senate voted whether to convict Trump for said high Crimes and Misdemeanors. Determining whether Trump violated the 14th Amendment is not up to House/Senate but up to the Supreme Court.

Comment: @Jan I thought the impeachment text contains exactly that accusation? Here: '**Section 3 of the 14th Amendment** to the Constitution prohibits any person who has “engaged in insurrection [...]" from “hold[ing] any office … under the United States”. In his conduct while President of the United States [...]Donald John Trump engaged in high Crimes and Misdemeanors by inciting violence against the Government of the United State' [...]. Donald John Trump thus warrants impeachment and trial, removal from office, and **disqualification to hold and enjoy any office** [...].'

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Yes, but I don't care what the Impeachment text contains. I'm arguing legally that neither branch of Congress has the power to determine whether Section 3 of the 14th Amendment applies to Donald J. Trump or any other participant in the events of 6th January. I'm arguing that Congress could try to pass an appropriate resolution but it would be up to the Supreme Court to decide whether that resolution was factual or counterfactual. In addition, disqualification to hold an office can be the result of the Senate trial after *every* Impeachment.

Comment: @Jan "disqualification to hold a [future] office can be the result of the Senate trial after every Impeachment" on which legal basis if not Am. 14,3?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica [Article I, Section 3, Clause 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_One_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_7:_Judgment_in_cases_of_impeachment;_Punishment_on_conviction)

Answer (score 22):

Perhaps surprisingly there is no bar on felons running for President, several have (though none have won). It seems likely that even an incarcerated person can be elected President. However there is one judicial act that would prevent a Trump presidency.

He could be convicted of a capital crime and executed.  The USA and several of the states still have capital punishment and you can't be elected President when you are dead.

Comment: “you can't be elected President when you are dead.” I know my request will sound ridiculous, but [citation needed]

Comment: @EkadhSingh: The closet real-life situation was in 1872, when one of the major candidates (Horace Greeley) died during the period between the popular vote and the Electoral College vote.  But he had lost anyway.

Comment: @EkadhSingh if you must... "https://www.srdlawnotes.com/2017/04/legal-status-of-dead-person.html"  the dead are not legal "persons".  Constituion article 2 repeatedly speaks of "person" (elector shall vote for for two persons, no person except a natural born citizen...) and so on.  So you can't be elected when you are dead.

Comment: Of course the Judicary can't just convict Trump, only a jury can do that.  And as far as I am aware, Trump has not committed any capital crime.  So this is a daft answer, not serious, please don't think it is anything more than *A Modest Proposal*.

Comment: Even if he were convicted of a capital crime, it's inconceivable that he would be executed before the election. Typically convicts spend a decade on death row, filing numerous appeals. And Trump certainly knows how to file appeals.

Comment: Which raises a new question: Could a sitting President be executed?

Comment: @Barmar Yes and "nobody knows" It is a daft answer, the only point of which is to emphasise how unlikely it is that any judicial action can disqualify Trump...."Nobody knows" Presidents may, or may not be immune from criminal prosecution.  The only vaguely realist execution scenario is if a rebellion overthrows the government, and the rebels execute the sitting president. But that is not a judicial act.

Comment: @JamesK In practice, I think the same arguments that were used to not indict a sitting President would also cause the courts to postpone any appeals on the conviction or sentence until they're out of office. Dealing with the court cases would interfere too much with their Presidential duties.

Comment: And this would almost certainly become the test case for "Can a President pardon themselves."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128002/discussion-between-james-k-and-barmar).

Comment: There are also some crimes that can include as part of the sentence being barred from holding office.  Trump's being convicted of any of these crimes is a rather more likely prospect than the scenario proposed here, although it is still perhaps unlikely since as far as I am aware the only active investigations at the moment are not federal.  Also on "only a jury can convict": the jury is acting as part of the judiciary branch, and the conviction is imposed on the court's authority.

Comment: There have been multiple times -- not many, but it's happened more than once -- when a dead person has been elected to a lower office.  Typically someone close to them, such as their widow, assumes the office when this happens.  In the case of a presidential election, it would most likely to go to their running mate, though I'm sure lawyers and constitutional scholars would have plenty of opinions on that subject!

Comment: -1 This answer is as useful as saying *"he could be run over by a bus and die, and then he wouldn't be able to take part in the next election"*.

Comment: At this point, I'm convinced that being incarcerated would actually increase his polling numbers.

Comment: @vsz, but that doesn't have anything to do with any judicial process, while the death penalty does.

Comment: "several of the states still have capital punishment and you can't be elected President when you are dead" - but death penalties usually take years to be carried out, so the more relevant question is, can you be elected President while on Death Row?

Comment: @EkadhSingh Not a ridiculous request at all.  I'm not aware of any rules about whether a deceased candidate can be elected as President, but I know of at least one case where a deceased candidate was elected to the Senate: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_Carnahan#2000_Senate_election_and_death

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "judicial"?

If you mean "legal/Constitutional", then the answer is no. Jan lists the Constitutional requirements to become president, and Trump meets them all.

One could speculate that Mr Trump may be convicted of some crime. But (a) he has not been convicted of any crime, so that would be purely hypothetical, and in any case (b) Nothing in the Constitution says that being convicted of a crime disqualifies a person from running for president.

And just to inject my personal opinion, I think a law saying that convicted criminals cannot be president would be problematic for at least two reasons: (a) It would be adding additional qualifications beyond what is in the Constitution. Would that be legal? It would establish a very dangerous precedent. It would mean that the party in power could pass laws deliberately crafted to keep someone they don't like from running for president. Like what if Congress passed a law saying that no one whose last name begins with "T" can be president? Even if you say, oh come on, that would be too obvious, they'd never get away with that politically ... okay, what if they did something more subtle, that one could at least make some pretense of justifying? Would it have to fool people, that the purpose of the law was NOT to target this one specific person? (b) If a criminal conviction could disqualify someone from becoming president, then political opponents would just have to find some jurisdiction somewhere where they could get a judge and jury to convict someone of a trumped up charge (no pun intended). This would allow 12 people anywhere in the country to overrule the majority of the voters.

Perhaps you think that Mr Trump incited the January 6 protest and that this was an act of treason. But "I and my friends think he was guilty" is not at all the same as being convicted. Pretty much every candidate for president in my lifetime has been called a traitor by opponents. You'd have to establish in court that Mr Trump actively encouraged the protestors to break the law despite his statements calling on them to remain "peaceful and patriotic" -- you have to assert that when he said "peaceful" this was a code word that he and they all understood to mean exactly the opposite. And you'd have to establish that this was an act of insurrection and not just a protest. Did 400 unarmed people think they were going to overthrow the government? How, exactly?

If you're thinking "judicial" in some other sense, like could the courts rule that Trump is ineligible ... on what grounds? They'd have to just make something up. Our courts have made some pretty wild rulings but for a judge to just declare, "I don't think this person would be a good president so therefore I'm going to rule that he's not allowed to run, regardless of what the voters think" ... Either that judge would quickly be knocked down by a higher court, or if the Supreme Court actually upheld it, I think we could fairly say that the country would no longer be a democracy in any sense.

Comment: With all respect, I've not mentioned anything of "I and my friends think he was guilty" in my question. US political standoff is interesting for me, but that doesn't mean, that I'm on one of sides.

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intent to say that you did. I said, "Perhaps you think ..." Note key word "perhaps". The wording of your question implies that you think there might be some legal or judicial issue, so I brought that up as a hypothetical. My point was to say that SOMEONE might say "I and my friends ...", not that you personally are one of those "someones".

Comment: It's ok, never mind.) I've asked that question, because it's rather unusual for me to see how sides in that US standoff using more and more power (administrative, judical, and any other) for making their opponent's life harder.

Comment: "Nothing in the Constitution says that being convicted of a crime disqualifies a person from running for president": but some crimes have, as one of the punishments available to the judge, such a disqualification.  See [my answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/67775/6927) for an example.

Comment: It might not be a question of the OP and his friends deciding, but of Congress deciding he was guilty, which would not be totally implausible in view of the fact that he's already been impeached twice.

Answer (score 2):

No. The Supreme Court has ruled in (at least) [Powell v. McCormack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell_v._McCormack) that the set of qualifications imposed by the Constitution are exclusive for offices that have their qualifications set out explicitly in the Constitution, which is true of both the President and Congress.

In that case, the Supreme Court ruled that, when determining the qualifications for a member of Congress,

> Congress is limited to the standing qualifications expressly prescribed by the Constitution.

The Congressional Research Service produced a [report to Congress (PDF)](https://web.archive.org/web/20080326231623/http://lugar.senate.gov/services/pdf_crs/Congressional_Candidacy_Incarceration_and_the_Constitutions_Inhabitancy_Qualification.pdf) on this subject. According to that report,

> **It is now well-settled that these three qualifications for office in the Constitution are the exclusive qualifications for Congress (and are not merely “minimum” qualifications), and that they are fixed and may not be supplemented by Congress nor by any State unilaterally. Specifically, there is no qualification in the Constitution that one not be a convicted felon (nor a “disqualification” for offenses other than in the 14th Amendment for certain treasonous conduct by those who have taken an oath of office).** Similarly, there is no qualification in the Constitution that a person, when elected to Congress, not be in prison. Furthermore, no State could permissibly implement such additional qualifications for federal office through election laws or ballot procedures. The Framers of the Constitution intentionally implemented a representative scheme whereby significant discretion is given and deference provided to the judgment and choice of the people as to whom they wish to have represent them in Congress.

The exact same reasoning should apply to the Presidency, as both have their qualifications laid out explicitly in the Constitution. No statute could legally place any further limits on these qualifications. The only way to add to them is to amend the Constitution. This has, of course, been done in the 14th Amendment (banning rebels from serving) and the 22nd Amendment (term limits for the President.)

While, as another answer mentions, there are plenty of U.S. federal statutes that allow or require a sentence upon conviction of a particular crime to include being banned from serving in various roles within the U.S. government, these limitations do not and can not extend to preventing anyone from being elected to Congress or the Presidency, nor from serving if elected. The only constitutional way to prevent someone from serving in those roles is for Congress to expel them (in the case of a member of Congress) or impeach them (in the case of a President.)

Answer (score -2):

Yes.  He could be convicted of bribery or a similar crime and barred as part of his sentence from holding public office.

[18 USC 201(b)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/201#b) (emphasis added):

> (b) Whoever—
>
> (1) directly or indirectly, corruptly gives, offers or promises anything of value to any public official or person who has been selected to be a public official, or offers or promises any public official or any person who has been selected to be a public official to give anything of value to any other person or entity, with intent—
> (A) to influence any official act; or
> (B) to influence such public official or person who has been selected to be a public official to commit or aid in committing, or collude in, or allow, any fraud, or make opportunity for the commission of any fraud, on the United States; or
> (C) to induce such public official or such person who has been selected to be a public official to do or omit to do any act in violation of the lawful duty of such official or person;
> (2) being a public official or person selected to be a public official, directly or indirectly, corruptly demands, seeks, receives, accepts, or agrees to receive or accept anything of value personally or for any other person or entity, in return for:
> (A) being influenced in the performance of any official act;
> (B) being influenced to commit or aid in committing, or to collude in, or allow, any fraud, or make opportunity for the commission of any fraud, on the United States; or
> (C) being induced to do or omit to do any act in violation of the official duty of such official or person;
> (3) directly or indirectly, corruptly gives, offers, or promises anything of value to any person, or offers or promises such person to give anything of value to any other person or entity, with intent to influence the testimony under oath or affirmation of such first-mentioned person as a witness upon a trial, hearing, or other proceeding, before any court, any committee of either House or both Houses of Congress, or any agency, commission, or officer authorized by the laws of the United States to hear evidence or take testimony, or with intent to influence such person to absent himself therefrom;
> (4) directly or indirectly, corruptly demands, seeks, receives, accepts, or agrees to receive or accept anything of value personally or for any other person or entity in return for being influenced in testimony under oath or affirmation as a witness upon any such trial, hearing, or other proceeding, or in return for absenting himself therefrom;
>
> shall be fined under this title or not more than three times the monetary equivalent of the thing of value, whichever is greater, or imprisoned for not more than fifteen years, or both, ***and may be disqualified from holding any office of honor, trust, or profit under the United States.***

If Trump were convicted of bribery, therefore, the judge could decide to impose the punishment of disqualification.  On the other hand, conviction for some other crimes carries this penalty automatically.  These include [treason](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2381), certain [recordkeeping offenses](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2071), and, perhaps not surprisingly, various crimes of [rebellion](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2383).  Title 18 USC 2383, emphasis added:

> Whoever incites, sets on foot, assists, or engages in any rebellion or insurrection against the authority of the United States or the laws thereof, or gives aid or comfort thereto, shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than ten years, or both; ***and shall be incapable of holding any office under the United States.***

I haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of all crimes for which the punishment of disqualification is available.

Comment: As JJJ alludes to, this answer is incorrect. Courts don't have the legal authority to ban someone from holding the office of President. Congress does (via impeachment,) but courts don't. Allowing courts to disqualify someone from running for office would be problematic for lots of reasons. In particular, it would be relatively easy to abuse such a power to disqualify political opponents. There's a reason why a 2/3 majority of the Senate is required.

Comment: @reirab that is a very appealing constitutional argument, but it is unfortunately entirely incorrect, because congress has granted the power to disqualify those convicted of certain crimes from holding federal office.  I have added the text of the linked statute to the answer so you can see for yourself.  I don't understand your concern about abuse for political opponents; there has to be a conviction.  So standing between any politician who wants to do this and his goal are are a federal prosecutor, a grand jury, a petit jury, and a federal judge with a life appointment.

Comment: Federal Statutes Imposing Collateral Consequences Upon Conviction, [Right to hold federal office or employment](https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/pardon/legacy/2006/11/13/collateral_consequences.pdf#page=4), "Various federal statutes, however, provide that a conviction may result in the loss of or ineligibility for office."

Comment: @phoog It's automatic for the case of "Whoever incites, sets on foot, assists, or engages in any rebellion or insurrection against the authority of the United States or the laws thereof, or gives aid or comfort thereto" because the 14th Amendment explicitly provides for that in the case of that specific action (Section 3.) This is merely an implementing statute of that provision.

Comment: @phoog 18 USC 201(b) is more interesting, though. I'm curious whether the provision allowing disqualification there has ever been tested in court, especially as it relates to holding the office of President, since the qualifications for that office are explicitly laid out in the Constitution and no power is granted by the Constitution to Congress to place additional terms on it, beyond exercise of impeachment sentencing power.

Comment: @phoog Upon a bit further research of this question, it seems that courts have already examined this question and have indeed ruled that such a limitation is unconstitutional. Just a few years after the law which included 18 USC 201 was passed, the Supreme Court ruled in [Powell v. McCormack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell_v._McCormack) that, "In judging the qualifications of its members under Art. I, § 5, Congress is limited to the standing qualifications expressly prescribed by the Constitution." While that case was in regards to Congress, surely the same would apply to the Presidency.

Comment: Incidentally, it appears that no justices dissented on that point. Only one justice dissented and his dissent was just on grounds that the case was moot by the time it reached the Supreme Court.

Comment: @reirab but Powell had not been sentenced to the punishment of disqualification by a court, and the only mention of disqualification in the constitution does implicitly allow such a punishment to be imposed judicially.  Furthermore, the [Crimes Act of 1790](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimes_Act_of_1790) imposes that punishment for the crime of judicial bribery.  So I wouldn't be so certain unless a court has explicitly and specifically ruled on the constitutionality of the punishment of disqualification as a sentence.

Comment: @reirab the impeachment provisions in the constitution limit the punishments that may be imposed through impeachment, but they do not actually limit explicitly the mechanisms that may be used to impose those punishments.  "The Party convicted shall nevertheless be liable and subject to Indictment, Trial, Judgment and Punishment, according to Law."  Were any delegates to the constitutional convention elected to the first congress?  What did they have to say about this law?

Comment: @phoog The unconstitutionality was specifically on the grounds that the Constitution itself provides all of the qualifications of the office for members of the Congress and, thus, any other qualifications cannot constitutionally be imposed. Or, in their own words, "Congress is limited to the standing qualifications expressly prescribed by the Constitution."

Comment: @phoog The vast majority of state and federal offices don't have their qualifications set out in the Constitution, so Congress setting additional qualifications - including judicially-applied ones - is fine for those. But the qualifications for members of Congress and for the President are set out in the Constitution and Congress cannot add to those except by Constitutional amendment, which is precisely what the Supreme Court ruled when the question was brought before them.

Comment: @reirab "any other qualifications cannot constitutionally be imposed": I understand the argument, but the opinion holds that congress cannot impose of its own volition additional criteria for seating a member.  I disagree that this necessarily excludes judicial _dis_-qualification of one duly convicted of a crime that has this penalty explicitly imposed by statute.  Any such case can easily be distinguished from _Powell,_ and until a court rules specifically on this question, it's unsettled law.

Comment: @phoog According to the Congressional Research Service, "It is now well-settled that these three qualifications for office in the Constitution
are the exclusive qualifications for Congress (and are not merely “minimum”
qualifications), and that they are fixed and may not be supplemented by Congress nor
by any State unilaterally. Specifically, there is no qualification in the Constitution
that one not be a convicted felon (nor a “disqualification” for offenses other than in
the14th Amendment for certain treasonous conduct by those who have taken an oath
of office)."

Comment: @phoog [source: CRS report for Congress, "Congressional Candidacy,
 Incarceration, and the Constitution’s
 Inhabitancy Qualification"](https://web.archive.org/web/20080326231623/http://lugar.senate.gov/services/pdf_crs/Congressional_Candidacy_Incarceration_and_the_Constitutions_Inhabitancy_Qualification.pdf)

Comment: While it's true that the President is not Congress, both are Constitutional officers with their qualifications laid out explicitly in the Constitution, so the same reasoning would apply to both.